# how to pass database values in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Am having several boxes(more than 100) that will create dynamically with

Now on each clicking of the box i should slide in one pop up box without page refresh.I downloaded jquery UI(http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-position) and used in my project.Now I want to pass the company id on each click of the box to get the details from database.if I click window 5 the company id 5 should pass the get all the other details of the company inside the dialog.

jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     // increase the default animation speed to exaggerate the effect
     $.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
     $(function () {

         $("#dialog").dialog({
             autoOpen: false,
             show: "slide",
             hide: "explode"
         });

         $("div[id *= 'window']").live('click', function (e) {

             $("#dialog").dialog("open");

             return false;
         });
     });
    </script>
```

Asp.net code

```
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
     <div><%#Eval("comp_name")%> </div>
      <div><%#Eval("comp_city")%> </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        $.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("div[id*='window']").live('click', function (e) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'YourUrl', type: 'Get', dataType: 'json',
                    data: { id: $(this).attr('id').replace(/window/g, '') },
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('<div></div>').appendTo('body').html('<div>' + data.comp_name + '</div><div>' + data.comp_city + '</div>').dialog({
                            modal: true, title: 'Test message', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
                            width: 460, height: 300, modal: true, resizable: false, closeOnEscape: false,
                            show: "slide", hide: "explode",
                            buttons: {
                                Ok: function () {
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                }
                            },
                            close: function (event, ui) {
                                $(this).remove();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
```

your using asp.net mvc 3?

```
$("div[id*='window']").live('click', function (e) {
            alert('Id : ' + $(this).attr('id') + '   ' + 'Replaced Id ' + $(this).attr('id').replace(/window/g, ''));
        });

<div id="window1">
    Click Me1 !
</div>
<br />
<div id="window2">
    Click Me2 !
</div>
<br />
<div id="Div1">
    Click Me !. I am not window id.
</div>
<br />
<div id="window3">
    Click Me3 !
</div>
```

fro live demo see this link: http://jsfiddle.net/nanoquantumtech/865Su/

for replace method see refer this link: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp

Comment: refer this link http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/96/Handling-JSON-Arrays-returned-from-ASP.NET-Web-Services-with-jQuery

Comment: No am not using MVC thanks for your answer,I will try with this!

Comment: k.. u need to use jquery ajax then only with out refreshing the page it will get data form database and u can display in jqueryui dialog..

Comment: Hi can you explain how you got the id in data.Am trying to use this code am having some difficulties in displaying the pop up.can u post some code to get id and also explain this replace(/window/g, '').Thanks!How can i get the id on each click while having dynamic boxes.

Comment: Thanks a lot,I think with this way surely i can finish this longing task without page refersh,but i want to show u some code behind code,my data is not takin properly it seems?How can i show the code can u follow my next que?thanks

Comment: please see the code here,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10749727/jquery-ajax-pop-up-error