# jquery ajax pop up error

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

I want to show the pop up of dynamic boxes.On each click i should get the corresponding id from database and display the details. I cant get the company id properly in the data of ajax jquery and pop up is not displaying.

code for jquery:

Am using jquery ui modal pop up

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
      $.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
      $(document).ready(function () {
          $("div[id*='window']").live('click', function (e) {
              $.ajax({
                  url: 'Default2.aspx/get_details',
                  type: 'Get', 
                  dataType: 'json',
                  data: { id: $(this).attr('id').replace(/window/g, '') },
                  success: function (data) {
                      $('<div></div>').appendTo('body').html('<div>' + data.comp_name + '</div><div>' + data.comp_name + '</div>').dialog({
                          modal: true, title: 'Test message', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
                          width: 460, height: 300, modal: true, resizable: false, closeOnEscape: false,
                          show: "slide", hide: "explode",
                          buttons: {
                              Ok: function () {
                                  $(this).dialog("close");
                              }
                          },
                          close: function (event, ui) {
                              $(this).remove();
                          }
                      });
                  }
              });
          });
      });


  </script>
```

My code behind:

```
public void get_details()
   {

       DataSet dset = new DataSet();
       SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=kar_WS4;Initial Catalog=datas;User ID=sa;Password=****");
       string qry = "Select comp_companyId,comp_name,comp_status from Company where comp_companyId=@comp_companyId ";
       SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(qry, cn);
       sda.Fill(dset);

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CompayJqueryUI.aspx.cs"
    Inherits="CompanyDisplay.CompayJqueryUI" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="Scripts/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("div[id*='window']").live('click', function (e) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "WebService.asmx/GetCompanyDetails", type: "Post", dataType: "json",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ id: $(this).attr('id').replace(/window/g, '') }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (msg) {
                        var data = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(eval("(" + msg.d + ")")));

                        $('<div></div>').appendTo('body').html('<div>' + data.Name + '</div><div>' + data.City + '</div>').dialog({
                            modal: true, title: 'Test message', zIndex: 10000, autoOpen: true,
                            width: 460, height: 300, modal: true, resizable: false, closeOnEscape: false,
                            show: "slide", hide: "explode",
                            buttons: {
                                Ok: function () {
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                }
                            },
                            close: function (event, ui) {
                                $(this).remove();
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (msg) {

                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="window1">
        Test1
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="window2">
        Test2
    </div>
</body>
</html>



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Entity;

namespace CompanyDisplay
{
    public partial class CompayJqueryUI : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public Company GetCompanyDetails(int id)
        {
            if (true)   //authorize 
            {
                //SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=KURIOS_WS4;Initial Catalog=Dreams;User ID=sa;Password=SageCRMv71");
                //string qry = "Select comp_companyId,comp_name,comp_status from Company where comp_companyId=@comp_companyId ";
                //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, cn);
                //SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                Company entity = new Company();
                entity.Id = 2;
                entity.Name = "Test";
                entity.City = "Bangalore";

                //Or

                //if (reader.Read())
                //{
                //    entity.Id = int.Parse(reader["comp_companyId"].ToString());
                //    entity.Name = reader["comp_name"].ToString();
                //    entity.City = reader["comp_status"].ToString();
                //}

                return entity;
            }
            else
            {
                return new Company();
            }
        }
    }
}



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using CompanyDisplay;

namespace CompanyDisplay
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [ScriptService]
    public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string GetCompanyDetails(int id)
        {
            return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new CompayJqueryUI().GetCompanyDetails(id));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: put one break point in this method  get_details and first it is firing or not... and return type is json use this line else remove this line dataType: 'json', form jquery

Comment: Hi great!on removing line datatype:json it is working,Inside popup it is saying as undefined,undefined.

Comment: on code behind i used the method u given it asks for namespace error as "type or name space json result could not be found"

Comment: refer this link how to add dlll for json : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45275/Create-a-JSON-WebService-in-ASP-NET-2-0-with-a-jQu  . using json or web sevice only it is possible.

Comment: I dint add the json ! am trying to load that dll.if i removed datatype:josin and alerted i got some thing like all my jquery code and atlast as,i cant fully add the code here!<form method="post" action="get_details?id=5" id="form1">
<div class="as

Comment: i tried with your last code.it says "name reader does nor exist in the current context"am i want to add json dll for reader?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11732/discussion-between-jeni-and-thulasiram)